# Laravel: Can't save user object to database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm following [this Laravel login/register tutorial on YouTube](http://youtu.be/KDkbYDbbt0o?t=14m6s) and I ran into a problem.

It seems I cannot insert the data from the `$user` object into my database.
Everything I have so far works perfectly fine until I reach the `$user->save()` method.

The following is my `AccountController.php`. You'll notice that I'm using `print_r` to try and debug the process. The first `print_r` gets printed to my page, but the second never does: Laravel just stops and outputs a cryptic `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` warning.

```
class AccountController extends BaseController {

    public function getCreate()
    {
        return View::make('account.create');
    }

    public function postCreate()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
                    'email' => 'required|max:64|min:3|email|unique:users',
                    'name' => 'required|max:64|min:3',
                    'password' => 'required|max:64|min:6'
        ));

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            // Return to form page with proper error messages
            return Redirect::route('account-create')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();
        }
        else
        {
            // Create an acount
            $email = Input::get('email');
            $name = Input::get('name');
            $password = Input::get('password');

            // Activation code
            $code = str_random(64);
            $user = User::create(array(
                        'active' => 0,
                        'email' => $email,
                        'username' => $name,
                        'password' => Hash::make($password),
                        'code' => $code
            ));

            if ($user)
            {
                // Send the activation link
                Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', array(
                    'link' => URL::route('account-activate', $code),
                    'name' => $name
                        ), function($message) use($user) {
                    $message
                            ->to($user->email, $user->username)
                            ->subject('Jasl | Activate your new account');
                });

                return Redirect::route('home')
                                ->with('success', 'One more step! You\'ll get an email from us soon. Please follow the activation link to activate your account.');
            }
        }
    }

    public function getActivate($code)
    {
        // Find user whose code corresponds to the one we've previously sent through email
        $user = User::where('code', '=', $code)->where('active', '=', 0);

        if ($user->count())
        {
            $user = $user->first();

            $user->active = 1;
            $user->code = '';

            echo '<pre>', print_r($user), '<pre>';
            if ($user->save())
            {
                echo '-----------------------';
                echo '<pre>', print_r($user), '<pre>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've googled a bit and found out that I should create a `$fillable` array in my `User` class, so I did it:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $fillable = array('active', 'name', 'email', 'password', 'password_temp', 'code', 'salt', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'pref_weight', 'pref_units', 'pref_time', 'pref_ener');

    use UserTrait,
        RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

Those are actually all the elements that my users table has.

This did not solve the problem.

What am I missing? Why isn't `$user->save()` working properly?

Comment: Have you checked the db to see if the changes are made? I don't think `$user->save()` returns anything, which is why you don't make it into that `if` block.

Comment: That `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` message is because you have debug set to false. Open your `app/config/app.php` file and set the `debug` key to true, and then try again.  This time, you'll get a page detailing the exception, and you can either debug from there, or update this question with the real error you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

My problem was that I created the `id` column of my users table with a custom name, `user_id`, instead of simply `id`. Apparently Laravel does not like this at all. The debugger pointed me to:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php
```

with the error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `users` set `active` = 1, `code` = , `updated_at` = 2015-01-20 21:28:14 where `id` is null)

I didn't know you shouldn't customize `id` columns. Renaming it solved the problem entirely and the database now updates correctly.

Thanks @patricus for the useful debugging tip, that's what allowed me to track this error down.